# What's the unix command to copy specific lines from one file to another file?

Tags: file, unix, awk, copy

I searched the web for hours, please excuse me if I overlooked something. I'm a beginner.
 I want to copy lines that include a certain string from file1 to file2. These lines from file 1 have to be inserted in file2, but only in specific lines that include another string.

(It's about the entire lines with the timecode)

Content of file1:

```
1
00:00:16,520 --> 00:00:23,200
Some text

2
00:00:25,800 --> 00:00:32,600
Some more text
```

Content of file2:

```
1
00: 00: 16,520 -> 00: 00: 23,200
Different text

2
00: 00: 25,720 -> 00: 00: 32,520
More different text
```

```
awk '/ --> /' file1
```

lists the lines I need from file1. But what do I have to add to the code to take these awk results and copy them only into the lines of file2 that include

```
'/ -> /'
```

??
Thanks a lot for your support!!!

Result in file2 should be:

```
1
00:00:16,520 --> 00:00:23,200
Different text

2
00:00:25,800 --> 00:00:32,600
More different text
```

Comment: Next time please show more of your initial attempt; it is barely sufficient to justify a good question. Additionally, the problem statement should have been stated clearly. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: below is for **GNU awk**

So you wanna replace timeline of subtitles, right?
Given that they're indentically indexed, i.e. the number above the timecode are the same.
Then you can try this:

```
awk 'ARGIND==1 && /^[0-9]+$/{getline timeline; tl[$0]=timeline;}ARGIND==2 &&/^[0-9]+$/{getline tmp2drop; print $0 ORS tl[$0];} ' file1 file2
```

Note that `/^[0-9]+$/` is the criterial, which match a whole line with a number only.
But if you have such subtitle text exists, then it will leads to error replace.

Another way is to use the line number(`FNR` denoted) as index:

```
awk 'ARGIND==1 && /-->/{tl[FNR]=$0} ARGIND==2 {if (/->/) print tl[FNR]; else print $0} ' file1 file2
```

But if the line number are not the same between two files, for example some subtitle texts are multiline, it still will replace wronly.

Given the occurances are at the relatively same places, we can manage a index on our own:

```
awk 'ARGIND==1 && /-->/{tl[i++]=$0} ARGIND==2 {if (/->/) print tl[j++]; else print $0} ' file1 file2
```

None of these are perfect, but to give you an idea how you could do the thing.
Choose depends on your situation, and improve the code yourself :)

note: They are just print to console, if you want replace the file. you can use `>` or '>>` to print the output to a temp file, and later rename to file2.
For example:

```
awk 'ARGIND==1 && /-->/{tl[i++]=$0} ARGIND==2 {if (/->/) print tl[j++]; else print $0} ' file1 file2 >> tmpFile2check
```

If you are not using GNU awk, `ARGIND==1` won't work, then use this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && /-->/{tl[i++]=$0} NR>FNR {if (/->/) print tl[j++]; else print $0} ' file1 file2 >> tmpFile2check
```

`NR` means the Number of Records, `FNR` means current File's Number of Records. If they are equal then it's the first file the script is dealing with. If `NR>FNR` means it's not the first file.
**Note** if file1 is or could be empty, then this mechanism will fail, then you should change to `FILENAME=="file1"` or other file checking method to avoid error processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I tried all of your suggestions, but with no success so far.  I keep trying, but as stated, I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: @piano_world Learn some basic of awk instead of search endlessly. Also check the last one I just updated.

Comment: did learn the basics, and knew about the output... still trying. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @piano_world It's hard to tell that you learned anything about awk. Your question  doesn't show your competence especially when augmented by "I'm just a beginner." Tiw is nice enough to help and "thanks anyways" isn't sufficient appreciation. Please consider up-voting his answer instead of leaving a thank you comment.

Comment: @Rafael hope I did it correctly now. Still new to this forum.

Comment: @Tiw ok. Your last edit works very well on Terminal ! Thank you once again. (note: my answer deleted)